# Proof: there exist $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ such that $xa+yb=\gcd (a,b)$

Tags: proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then there exist $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $xa+yb=d$.

I don't really understand the proof for this theorem.

They state the following (translation):

> We are going to construct two sequences of integers $x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots$ and $y_0,y_1,y_2,\dots$ such that
>   $$
> x_na+y_nb=r_n.
> $$
>   For $n=0$ we have $r_n=|a|=\pm a$, so we can take $x_0=\pm 1$ and $y_0=0$. In the same way we can take $x_1=0$ and $y_1=\pm 1$. If $n\geq1$, and $r_n\neq0$, then we can determine $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ by subtraction $q_n$ times
>   $$
> x_na+y_nb=r_n
> $$
>   from
>   $$
> x_{n-1}a+y_{n-1}b=r_{n-1}.
> $$
>   Because $r_{n-1}-q_nr_n=r_{n+1}$, this gives
>   $$
> (x_{n-1}-q_nx_n)\cdot a+(y_{n-1}-q_ny_n)\cdot b=r_{n+1},
> $$
>   so we can choose $x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}-q_nx_n$ and $y_{n+1}=y_{n-1}-q_ny_n$. Continuing this way, we will eventually get $r_m=0$, and then we have
>   $$
> x_{m-1}a+y_{m-1}b=r_{m-1}=d.
> $$

I have two questions concerning this proof:

1) Do we need that $|a|\geq|b|$?

2) How do we determine $q_n$?

3) And why is the last line true;
$$
x_{m-1}a+y_{m-1}b=r_{m-1}=d.
$$

Comment: Just a note: this is called Bezout's lemma.  This is one of two pretty standard ways of proving it.  You might like the other one more.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Yes, the other one (which I found on wikipedia) is much clearer to me.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) for the idea behind this row-reduction form of the Extended Euclidean algorithm for computing the Bezout equation for the gcd,Above $q_n$ comes from dividing $r_{n-1}$ by $r_n$. Essentiallly we are modding out the prior equation by the current one in order to decrease the $\,r_i\,$ till it equals the gcd. Follow the link for details.

Comment: The numbers $x_n, y_n$ in that proof are produced by the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.  Giving this proof without explaining the algorithm is bad teaching.  Other proofs (e.g. wikipedia as mentioned) are much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some answers, hope they help:

Starting with

2. Given $r_{n-1}$ and $r_n$, we find $r_{n+1}$ by Euclidean division: we divide $r_{n-1}$ by $r_n$, writing uniquely $$r_{n-1} = q r_n + r, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\leq r < r_n$$
   We then set $q_n = q$ and $r_{n+1}= r$.  So $q_n$ is just determined by division with remainder.

Now

1. Given the answer to 2), no you do not need to take $|a| \geq |b|$.  For example, if you took $a=3$ and $b=5$, this method would have $3,5,3,2,1,0$ as the sequence $(r_n)$.  We just waste a step in the beginning. This illustrates the general pattern, if $r_0 < r_1$, we force $r_2 = r_0$ and then get back on track.

Finally

3. From the answer to 2), the sequence $(r_n)$ is generated by running the Euclidean algorithm on $|a|, |b|$.  I assume that you've already encountered and understood the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Ahh, now I see. So they're basically using the Euclidean algorithm, but they subtract the equations, so that we get the form $ax+by=ggd(a,b)$ eventually.

Comment: Yep, exactly! On the right side of the equation we just do the Euclidean algorithm. But we use the information from each step of the algorithm to pull along the left side of the equation.  Hence, "extended Euclidean algorithm." The extended algorithm is actually identical to the original, but we keep track of additional information.